# When should functions take cstrings instead of strings? (C++)

Tags: c++, string, function, c++11, parameter-passing

So I've been exploring [folly](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/docs/Overview.md)- Facebook's open source library, and most of their utility functions take cstrings instead of strings.  Why do they do this?  The examples pass in a reference to std::string and it is implicitly converted to a cstring.  Here is an example function of theirs, that I'd like this question to focus on:

**How the function is called:**

```
// Multiple arguments are okay, too. Just put the pointer to string at the end.
toAppend(" is ", 2, " point ", 5, &str);
```

**Inside Conv.h**

```
/**
* Everything implicitly convertible to const char* gets appended.
*/
template <class Tgt, class Src>
typename std::enable_if<
  std::is_convertible<Src, const char*>::value
  && detail::IsSomeString<Tgt>::value>::type
toAppend(Src value, Tgt * result) {
  // Treat null pointers like an empty string, as in:
  // operator<<(std::ostream&, const char*).
  const char* c = value;
  if (c) {
    result->append(value);
  }
}
```

When should functions take cstrings instead of strings?  Why didn't they write the function to take a std::string by reference, and thus the function could be called like this:

```
toAppend(" is ", 2, " point ", 5, str);
```

My only guess is for efficiency, but Is it more efficient to convert a std::string into a cstring than it is to pass a reference of std::string?  Maybe the actual manipulation of a cstring is done quicker than calling std::string member functions? Or maybe that way some could call the function if they only had a cstring to begin with? hmmm

Comment: It's taking in std::string* and not std::string& as you suggest. Its not taking in const char*. Internally std::string* std::string & are the same. References are generally preferred but they may have done it consistency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a common convention designed to highlight the fact that the last argument is an output. Usually, it's best to define arguments using a reference instead of a pointer because references are guaranteed to not be null, but some people like to see `&` when calling the function to remind themselves the argument is an output.

Comment: does this answer the question? I thought the question was why C string rather than C++ string, not why pointer rather than reference.

Comment: The answer is, they are not taking C string there. They are taking pointer to std::string.